# Not able to import file as module in python 3.7

Tags: python, virtualenv

```
python -V
Python 3.7.6

which python
python: aliased to python3.7

which python3.7
/path/to/virtualenvfolder/bin/python3.7
```

Folder structure

```
src
 |-- __init__.py
 |-- migrations
     |-- env.py
```

## env.py

```
from config import DB, DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_PORT, DB_DRIVER
```

Error

```
File "src/migrations/env.py", line 13, in <module>
    from config import DB, DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_PORT, DB_DRIVER
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

but if change to

`from src.config import DB, DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_PORT, DB_DRIVER`

instead of

`from config import DB, DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_PORT, DB_DRIVER`

It works.

Comment: what's  the issue?

Comment: Which command are you running? What lead to this error message?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're trying to import config as if it were in the same package level as env.py.

You must use `from src.config import` or `from ..config import` because python needs to know where to look on its path for config.py

Comment: This is an existing project and I can not go and change path in every file. I am sure there is something which I am missing.